# SQLAlchemy: Referencing labels in SELECT subqueries

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to figure out how to replicate the below query in SQLAlchemy

```
SELECT c.company_id AS company_id,
  (SELECT policy_id FROM associative_table at WHERE at.company_id = c.company_id) AS policy_id_ref,
  (SELECT `default` FROM policy p WHERE p.policy_id = policy_id_ref) AS `default`,
FROM company c;
```

Note that this is a stripped down, basic example of what I'm really dealing with. The actual schema supports data and relationship versioning that requires the subqueries to include additional conditions, sorting, and limiting, making it impractical (if not impossible) for them to be joins.

The crux of the problem is in how the second subquery relies on policy_id_ref -- the value obtained from the first subquery. In SQLAlchemy, this is effectively what I have now:

```
ct = aliased(classes.company)
at = aliased(classes.associative_table)
pt = aliased(classes.policy)

policy_id_ref = session.query(at.policy_id).\                       
    filter(at.company_id == ct.company_id).\
    label('policy_id_ref')             

policy_default = session.query(pt.default).\
    filter(pt.id == 'policy_id_ref').\              
    label('default')

query = session.query(ct.company_id,policy_id_ref,policy_default)
```

The pull from the "company" table works fine as does the first subquery that retrieves the "policy_id_ref" column. The problem is the second subquery that has to reference that "policy_id_ref" column. I don't know how to write its filter in such a way that it literally renders "policy_id_ref" in the resulting query, to match the label of the first subquery.

Suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well you can't do that in SQL. You can't do `SELECT tbl.foo AS bar, bar AS baz FROM tbl;`. You need a subquery to work around that.

Comment: @univerio I'm not quite sure how you concluded that's what I'm trying to do. An example of the MySQL syntax I'm trying to achieve is at the top of my post and is indeed based around subqueries.

Comment: Because that's exactly what you wrote you are doing? You're trying to refer to `policy_id_ref` in the definition of `default`, aren't you?

Comment: @univerio Your "You can't do" query is nothing like what I'm trying to build, and what I'm trying build (at the top of the question) most certainly does work in MySQL. Yes, I'm referring to "policy_id_ref" in the second subquery's filter because "policy_id_ref" will exist and be available when the subqueries are combined in the final query. Just like in my original queries.

Comment: I think this is one of those things that only works in MySQL and nowhere else because it's against the SQL spec. Example: [mysql](http://rextester.com/TTEZD38102) | [postgres](http://rextester.com/JEYKD60847) | [sql server](http://rextester.com/QXVZU67098) | [oracle](http://rextester.com/SSBDA88795). Hence, I don't know how well this is supported in SQLAlchemy, given that this seems like a MySQL-specific quirk. You can try using `literal_column("policy_id_ref")` which skips all the SQLAlchemy validations for column names.

Comment: @univerio "literal_column()" got it working and answered the question. If you want to retool that as an answer response, I'll flag it as correct. As for MySQL, +1 I say. It's a nice capability to have in SELECT clause subqueries for quick queries and pinched timetables. Using JOIN subqueries have more power but can take longer to get right, but with a bit of nesting I think I'm onto a solution there, after all. Still, good to have this answered.

Comment: I think you'd use [LATERAL subqueries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html) for such in others, which at least to me make a lot more sense than co-dependent select list expressions. Your simplified example looks like it'd easily convert to simple joins, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your query as

```
select(
   Companies.company_id,
   AssociativeTable.policy_id.label('policy_id_ref'),
   Policy.default.label('policy_default'), 
).select_from(
   Companies,
).join(
   AssociativeTable,
   AssociativeTable.company_id == Companies.company_id,
).join(
   Policy,
   AssociativeTable.policy_id == Policy.id  
)
```

but in case you need reference to label from subquery => use `literal_column`

```
from sqlalchemy import func, select, literal_column

session.query(
    func.array_agg(
        literal_column('batch_info'),
        JSONB
    ).label('history')
).select_from(
    select(
        func.jsonb_build_object(
            'batch_id', AccountingQueueBatch.id,
            'batch_label', AccountingQueueBatch.label,
        ).label('batch_info')
    ).select_from(
        AccountingQueueBatch,
    )
)
```